# Java Script - Problem changing background colour of a grid cell

Tags: javascript

I have a 4x4 grid that I populate with text. The user can click on any cell and the background colour should change to blue. Clicking again reverts to cyan. All that works, however, the maximum amount of cells that can be selected is 4. The problem is I can click as many cells as I wish. I also found, when debugging, is that at the console.log line I am getting an error ‘undefined background color’. This may or may not be connected with my main problem. Totally stuck on this and I am very much an amateur with js. Code below:

```
function toggleSelection(event) {
  document.getElementById("cell").setAttribute("style", "backgroundColor: cyan"); //
    
  const selectedCell = event.target;

  console.log(selectedCell.style.backgroundColor);  
  if (selectedCell.style.backgroundColor !== 'blue') {   // console.log('Cell clicked');//
    selectedCell.style.backgroundColor = 'blue';  
    selectedCount++;  
  } else {  
    selectedCell.style.backgroundColor = 'cyan';  
    selectedCount--;  
  }  
  if (selectedCount === 4) {  
    cells.forEach(cell =\> {  
      cell.removeEventListener('click', toggleSelection);  
    });  
    submitButton.disabled = false;  
  }
}
```

Tried debugging with console.log. Same results.

Comment: `backgroundColor: cyan` isn't valid css, try using `background-color: cyan`

Comment: I assume `cell =\>` is a typo

Comment: Where/how is `selectedCount` defined?

Comment: but also.. where is cells defined, and submitButton. Those are just details. The main problem as already pointed out was using `backgroundColor` inside the inline style. Also the arrow operator typed wrongly. But those were already highlighted as mistakes. To go further than that is impossible because it's not clear what's supposed to be `cells`... maybe the selected cells.. but you didn't add any logic giving value to that variable

Comment: as a humble suggestion, instead of setting the style directly you may use classes (`el.classList.add('selected')`) and have css rules styling those elements accordingly. That way you may have a strategy to better select elements having a given quality... like `document.querySelectorAll('.selected')` for example... if you are not keeping track of the events

Comment: If i change backgroundColor to background-color I get errors in java.

Comment: Sorry cell = \> was a typo when i copied into here. I should have shown the two preceding lines:  let selectedCount = 0;

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', toggleSelection);

Comment: @RickS650 only change it here `setAttribute("style", "backgroundColor: cyan")` -- (also javascript, not java)